# vim: open NERDTree and move the cursor to the file editing area

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I tried following the instruction in FAQ section on NERDTree github site:

"Q. How can I open a NERDTree automatically when vim starts up?"

"A. Stick this in your vimrc: `autocmd vimenter * NERDTree`"

It works but when I open a file the cursor stay in the NEARDTree explorer area but not in the edit area, I have to press `Ctrl+w+l` to move it back, what should I write in my `.vimrc` file to automate setting the cursor in the edit area?

Comment: Alternatively don't use NerdTree or more specifically avoid the drawer. Here is a nice Vimcast article: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/). Personally I rarely have a need for the use of a file explorer. I find simple tab completion, fuzzy finders, ctags/cscope, and Tim Pope's [Projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) fill my needs without wasting any space or opening up annoying splits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make NERDtree not be the default window when VIM starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253080/make-nerdtree-not-be-the-default-window-when-vim-starts)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just add this second command right after:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

Or if you want a one-liner

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! By the way, does your one-liner omit a `p` in the end? I get an error without it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the default behavior if no file is specified (i.e. leave the NERDTree explorer *only* if there is a file to edit) you can use this setting:

`autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 | NERDTree | wincmd p | endif`

Comment: You forgot the default action. Full line should be `autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 | NERDTree | wincmd p | else | NERDTree | endif`.